# Show nested circles on ggplot: polygons disappear when limited xy axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry

I am trying to show two nested circles in my ggplot object using `ggforce::geom_circle` that look like this:

[image]

It definitely works when I am plotting two circles:

[image]

but if I try to limit the x and y axis using `scale_x` or `coord_cartesian` either my polygons are weirdly cut, or not shown:

[image]

What can be the issue?

Here is a dummy example:

```
library(ggforce)

set.seed(4242)
dd <- data.frame(x = runif(20, min=0, max=2),
                 y = runif(20, min=0, max=2))


# There's presumably a way to do this within the above mutate function using case_when()
ggplot(dd) +
  
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = 2),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = 'grey90',
              lty = 'dotted', color = 'grey70', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = 0.5),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = 'grey70',
              lty = 'dotted', color = 'grey50', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), size=1)+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope=0.5, col='red') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope=1.8, col='blue') +
  #scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 2)) +
  #scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,2.5),   # try to limit the xy axis in two ways
                  ylim = c(0,2.5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme_update(legend.position = 'bottom') +
  theme_update(aspect.ratio=1)
```

Session info:

```
    R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggforce_0.4.1 ggplot2_3.3.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7       magrittr_2.0.2   MASS_7.3-54      tidyselect_1.1.2
 [5] munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_2.0-2 R6_2.5.1         rlang_1.0.2     
 [9] fansi_1.0.2      dplyr_1.0.8      tools_4.1.1      grid_4.1.1      
[13] gtable_0.3.0     utf8_1.2.2       cli_3.2.0        DBI_1.1.2       
[17] withr_2.5.0      ellipsis_0.3.2   digest_0.6.28    assertthat_0.2.1
[21] tibble_3.1.6     lifecycle_1.0.1  crayon_1.5.0     farver_2.1.0    
[25] tweenr_1.0.2     purrr_0.3.4      vctrs_0.3.8      glue_1.6.2      
[29] labeling_0.4.2   polyclip_1.10-4  compiler_4.1.1   pillar_1.7.0    
[33] generics_0.1.2   scales_1.1.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: Limiting the axis using scales would be expected to cause this problem, but I can't replicate your problem if I use the coord_cartesian method - it works just fine on my pc. Have you tried using different drawing devices - X11, ragg, png, pdf etc?

Comment: I am on windows. I have tried export it to `png` but was the same. I will try with `pdf` one. Thank you for suggestions @Allan Cameron!

Comment: Sounds related to the following issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4498

Comment: @AllanCameron, indeed, the export to pdf works great, showing both circles! Weird. Thank youf or suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aa @teuenbrand pointed out, this issues have been discussed [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4498) and was happening on later installations of R 4.1.0 oon Windows 10. These two options succesfully print the plot into pdf or png format, but still the plotting is not proper with R studio itself.

**Workarounds:**

1. printing the figure into `pdf` (not to png), suggested by @AllanCameron:

   ```
   pdf("output.pdf")
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:10, ymin = 1:10, ymax = 10 + 1:10), aes(x)) +
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = 0.5) +
      coord_cartesian(c(1, 9))
    dev.off()
   ```
2. printing to `png`: [recommened](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4498) to use the `ragg` package, and print plot using `agg_png` command:

   ```
   library(ragg)
   agg_png("output2.png")

   library(ggplot2)
   ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:10, ymin = 1:10, ymax = 10 + 1:10), aes(x)) +
   geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = 0.5) +
   coord_cartesian(c(1, 9))

   dev.off()
   ```

**Plotting of two polygons while cropping the xy-plot limits:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could force the origin to 0 with `expand` and no limit in `scale_*_continuous` like this:

```r
library(ggforce)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(4242)
dd <- data.frame(x = runif(20, min=0, max=2),
                 y = runif(20, min=0, max=2))

ggplot(dd) +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = 2),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = 'grey90',
              lty = 'dotted', color = 'grey70', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = 0.5),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = 'grey70',
              lty = 'dotted', color = 'grey50', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), size=1)+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope=0.5, col='red') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope=1.8, col='blue') +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,2.5),   # try to limit the xy axis in two ways
                  ylim = c(0,2.5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme_update(legend.position = 'bottom') +
  theme_update(aspect.ratio=1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank your for your answer @Quinten! Still, when  run your code, my polygons are again missing, now both of them. Any other workaround?

Comment: @maycca, The polygons are still missing when you run exactly my code? Could you please share your session info?

Comment: no, they are still missing. I have added my session Info. Seems that I have a correct version of ggplot and R?